# How to when holding item and stat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi I'm trying to create a server. But one command I can't get. I'm trying to make it when I hold an item and stat.jump are both on effect me with levitation and I can't get it right. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to setup a stat.jump objective as well as something that checks for the item in the active slot, like this:

```
/scoreboards players tag @a add itemSelected {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}}
```

then the reset of the commands would look a little something like this:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=itemSelected] remove itemSelected
 {insert detection command from above here}
/effect @a[tag=itemSelected,score_jump_min=1] levitation
/scoreboard players set @a[score_jump_min=1] jump 0
```

and there you have it, that's how to do that.

---

**EDIT**: Here is a command-for-command rundown of how to do this:

run this command in the chat once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add jump stat.jump
```

then set up a [repeating-chain line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2NRO.jpg) (the first is repeating, the others all chain) with the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=itemSelected] remove itemSelected
/scoreboards players tag @a add itemSelected {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}}
/effect @a[tag=itemSelected,score_jump_min=1] levitation 1 4
/scoreboard players set @a[score_jump_min=1] jump 0
```

you obviously need to change two things in here:

1. the level and duration of the [levitation effect](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#effect)
2. the actual item you want to test for (in my example this part: `{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}`). You want to input the [name of the item](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Item_IDs).

Comment: Can you please make it simpler like I'm really new. xD

Comment: i added some more. are you able to make it work now?